# Make MSal for angular 2+ not to redirect after login

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I want to use msal for angular to generate a token, which i am gonna use to authenticate in another api. I need msal to get the azure ad token, do something, then manually redirect, but msal automatically redirects after it logs in, which i do not want, since my app is expecting a token from the api number two, and the guard that i implemented in my Angular app says i am not logged in and redirects me to msal's login screen again (expected since the login in the API 2 takes some time and i do not have yet its token, which i validate inside the guard to say whether i am logged in or not..)

this is the code I've tried so far:

```
this.loginSubscription = this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:loginSuccess', () => {
      this.msalToken = sessionStorage['msal.idtoken'];
      this.getPhoto();

      this.authUserService.hasTerms().subscribe(
        Response => {
          const hasTerms:boolean = Response['hasAcceptedTherms'];
          
          if(!hasTerms){
            this.router.navigate([''])
            this.modal.showTermsAndConditions().subscribe(response => {
                const declined:boolean = response['declined'];
                if(declined)
                {
                   this.router.navigate(['accessDenied']);
                   return;
                }
                this.authUserService.auth().subscribe(next => {  
                this.router.navigate(['msd-homepage']);
                });                
              });
              return;  
          }      
          else{
            this.authUserService.auth().subscribe(next => {  
            this.router.navigate(['msd-homepage']);});
          }    
        }, error => console.log(error));           
    });
```

this is my module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MsalModule } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { LogLevel } from 'msal';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UnauthorizedInterceptor } from './interceptors/unauthorized.interceptor';
import { MsalAuthRoutingModule } from './msal-auth-routing.module';

const protectedResourceMap: Array<[string, string[]]> = [['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read', 'user.read.all']]];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MsalAuthRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${environment.tenantId}`,
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: environment.clientUrl,
      cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      popUp: false,
      consentScopes: ['user.read', 'user.read.all', 'group.read.all'],
      unprotectedResources: ['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'],
      protectedResourceMap,
      logger: loggerCallback,
      correlationId: '1234',
      level: LogLevel.Info,
      piiLoggingEnabled: true
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: UnauthorizedInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class MsalAuthModule { }

export function loggerCallback(logLevel, message, piiEnabled) {
  if (!environment.production) {
    console.log('MSAL logging => ' + message);
  }
}
```

Here's my guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { AuthUserService } from '../services/auth-user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthUserGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authUserService: AuthUserService, private msalservice:MsalService) { }

  public canActivate():boolean {

    if(this.authUserService.isLoggedIn())
    {      
      return true;
    }     

    else{   
      this.msalservice.loginRedirect();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

if there's something else i can provide please tell me, thanks.